# Change color for grouped plot and configure legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the following code (from stack overflow, thank you to the community!) to plot the proportions of different groups over time.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date)) %>% #convert date to date
  group_by(group, date) %>% #group
  summarise(prop = sum(outcome=="1")/n()) %>% #calculate proportion 
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = prop, color = group))+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = prop, color = group))
```

The sample data frame used is this:

```
date <- c("2000-05-01", "2000-05-01", "2000-05-01", "2000-05-02", "2000-05-02", "2000-05-02", "2000-05-02", "2000-05-03", "2000-05-03", "2000-05-03", "2000-05-04", "2000-05-04")
outcome <- c("1", "0", "0", "0","1","1","0", "1","1","0", "1","0")
group <- c("1", "2", "3", "2", "1", "1", "2", "3", "2", "1", "1", "3")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(date, outcome, group))
```

Printing the line chart, I want to change the automatically assigned colors for each group but can't figure out how. Can someone help me with this?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: I also want to include manual labels for the Groups and change the legend title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `scale_color_*()` functions from ggplot2. If you want to specify specific colors, use `scale_color_manual()`. You can provide named vectors to the `values =` parameter to set specific color values for that color group and to the `labels =` parameter to set custom text in the legend:

```
ggplot(...) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('1' = 'yellow', '2' = 'orange', '3' = 'black'),
                       labels = c('1' = 'fish', '2' = 'cats', '3' = 'dogs'))
```

The `scale_color_brewer()` function lets you choose from set palettes designed and tested on discrete data. If you don't need specific colors, these palettes often make your plots clearer than they would be if you picked colors arbitrarily.

To modify the legend, use the `guides()` function:

```
ggplot(...) +
    guides(color = guide_legend(title = 'Animal Kinds:'),
           shape = guide_legend(title = 'Food Type:'))
```

This lets you control all your legends in one place. You can specify titles and pretty much every visual parameter for how the legend will appear. See `?guide_legend` for a list of all the parameters you can change in `guide_legend()`

Comment: Excellent, thank you! What would be the best way to modify the legend to display costumed text?

Comment: This worked excellently; however, I can't find a way to change the legend title; I was researching and found this in addition
`  scale_fill_manual("legend Title", values = c("00", "011")) + ` but it doesn't work. Is this overridden by the command in `scale_color_manual()` or what am I doing wrong...?

Comment: `scale_fill_manual()` is going to control the scale for `fill` and won't change anything about the aesthetic `color`. I would suggest using the `guides()` function to modify the legend.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your comment about changing the title: the easiest way to modify the title is to use

```
ggplot(...) +
scale_color_manual(values = c('1' = 'green', '2' = 'yellow', '3' = 'red'),
                   labels = c('1' = 'A', '2' = 'B', '3' = 'C'),
                   name = "Legend Title")
```